Value is getting assigned to the wrong row on a multi-dimensional array
// Print an nxn magic square

#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n;
    printf("This program creates a magic square of a specified size.\n");
    printf("The size must be an odd number between 1 and 99.\n");
    printf("Enter size of the square: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    int square[n] [n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            square[i] [j] = 0;
        }
    }
    
    square[0] [n / 2] = 1;

    int row = 0, column = n/2;
    for (int i = 2; i < n * n + 1; i++) {
        if (square[row == 0 ? n - 1 : row - 1] [(column + 1) % n] == 0) {
            square[row == 0 ? row = n - 1 : --row] [(++column) % n] = i;
        } else {
            square[++row] [column] = i;
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
                printf("%2d ", square[j] [k]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}


I'm trying to print a magic square (all rows, columns and diagonals sum to the same number). The way I'm trying to do this is to start by placing 1 in the middle of row 0, and from there assign the next number to the row before one column over (if it exceeds the array bounds it wraps around), if there is already a number there put the next one directly below the number printed before. But for some odd reason when the else clause is executed (the latter happens), it assigns i to the wrong row. Changing the else statement in the program above to this gives the following output:
        } else {
            square[printf("row: %d ", row), row] [column] = i;
        }

Row prints as 1 and it keeps assigning the value to row 2.:
 0  0  1  0  0
 0  0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  2  0

 0  0  1  0  0
 0  0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0  3
 0  0  0  2  0

 0  0  1  0  0
 0  0  0  0  0
 4  0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0  3
 0  0  0  2  0

 0  0  1  0  0
 0  5  0  0  0
 4  0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0  3
 0  0  0  2  0

row: 1
 0  0  1  0  0
 0  5  0  0  0
 4  6  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0  3
 0  0  0  2  0

row: 1
 0  0  1  0  0
 0  5  0  0  0
 4  7  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0  3
 0  0  0  2  0
.
.
.

sorry if this is unclear, I'm new to programming.

What is column at that time?

The code you posted never ran as you are missing a }.  Please revise question.

Always check return value from I/O operations like scanf() otherwise you may be operating on uninitialized variables.  If n is large enough your program will fail so you should check that n is reasonable sized.  negative values would be undefined.

Please use text for your output data instead of an image.  The output also doesn't match your program (which never prints "row 1").

@DavisHerring That was it! I forgot to assign column to to its "wrapped around" value in square[row == 0 ? row = n - 1 : --row] [(++column) % n] = i;, just incrementing it instead, which was causing column to be out of bounds and was causing this mysterious behavior. Changing it to 'square[row == 0 ? row = n - 1 : --row] [column = (column + 1) % n] = i;' did it. Thank you :D

It would be good if you can fix the inconsistency in question two code snippets vs output then write up an answer to your question

@AllanWind sorry about that, this is my first post here. The output matches if you change the else clause in the program to the else clause over the screenshot.

Nothing to be sorry about.  I am just helping you get the most out of your friends here on stackoverflow.

Side note: be aware of VLA (Variable length arrays) as you wrote int square[n] [n];.

square[row == 0 ? row = n - 1 : --row] [(++column) % n] = i; in the if statement is incrementing column without "wrapping around" the array, causing column to be out of bounds, which is producing the undesired behavior. Changing it to square[row == 0 ? row = n - 1 : --row] [column = (column + 1) % n] = i; works just fine.

Style guide: you should not put spaces before or between array subscripts.  They are postfix operators and bind very tightly (similar to the dot . and arrow -> operators).  Use int array[n][n]; etc.

I agree the revised syntax works; I don't think it is very readable.  I think I'd use: row = (row == 0) ? n - 1 : row - 1; column = (column + 1) % n; square[row][column] = i; to separate the three assignments.  Your notation in the debugging else clause — square[printf("row: %d ", row), row] [column] = i; is likewise ghastly (for all it works).  Use: printf("row: %d\n", row); square[row][column] = i;, especially since you already have braces around the whole else block.  It is also much easier to remove the debugging printf if it is on a separate line.
